# Getting static resources from a diff host in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible i can load the images in webpage, if my image directory is in diff host which is in same domain.

Currently i am fetching those images from my resource folder(app) which is in my local.

Is there any module to do it in a simple way, please suggest.

Comment: Just load it via full path url.

Comment: what i know you need to specify the relative path for displaying images.

Comment: Show code, that doesn't work for you.